# IE automation via Outlook - Permission Denied issues

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

```
Sub test()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objShellWindows As Object
    Dim objWin As Object

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each objWin In objShellWindows
        If TypeName(objWin.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            Debug.Print objWin.Document.Location
        End If
    Next objWin 
End Sub
```

This works perfectly fine in Excel, Access, Word and PowerPoint, but throws "Run-Time error 70 - Permission Denied" error on the `Debug.Print` line when ran from Outlook. I'm using late binding to rule out references issues. Also went through Outlook macro settings and compared them with the other Office apps - all seems fine to me. Why is it failing in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. returns same as Location

```
Debug.Print objWin.Document.Url
```

thanks